# Congruence on semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, congruence-relations

> For a commutative semigroup $S$, define the relation $\theta_n^S\ \ (n\geqslant 1)$ by $$a\theta_n^Sb\text{ if and only if } (\forall x\in S^n) xa = xb. $$
>   (a) Show that $\theta_n^S$ is a congruence on $S$, and that $$\theta_1^S\subseteq\theta_2^S\subseteq\cdots$$
>   (b) Show that $\theta_n^S=1_S$ for all $n$ if $S$ is a monoid.
>
> (c)For $n=1,2,\ldots,$ denote $S/\theta_n^S$ by $S_n$. Show that, for all $n\geqslant 2$, $$S_n\simeq S_{n-1}/\theta_1^{S_{n-1}}. $$

How can i solve the second portion of part (a)?First portion of part (a) is easy one for me but i stuck on the second portion.
Any help in this regard.

Comment: Please do not use a picture but type the statement of your problem. Make sure that all definitions are given (for instance $S^n$).

Comment: Is $S^n$ supposed to be the set of all $n$-fold products of elements of $S$ (as opposed to the set of $n$-tuples of $S$)?

Comment: Suppose $a\theta^S_k b$. Then for all $x\in S^k$, $xa=xb$. If $y\in S^{k+1}$, then there exists $z\in S$ such that $y=zx$ with $x\in S^k$; so...